# php get value from json multi array

Tags: php, json

my json

```
                {
                 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
                 "etag": "\"kuL0kDMAqRo3pU7O0pwlO-Lfzp4/jqg44GhTcPEjvonmtziBVF9YNxI\"",
                 "pageInfo": {
                  "totalResults": 1,
                  "resultsPerPage": 1
                 },
                 "items": [
                  {
                   "kind": "youtube#video",
                   "etag": "\"kuL0kDMAqRo3pU7O0pwlO-Lfzp4/yzEFa8A9Vx0owofp9PtbSXuFmIs\"",
                   "id": "mWPdC6QB0v4",
                   "contentDetails": {
                    "duration": "PT1H53M27S",
                    "dimension": "2d",
                    "definition": "sd",
                    "caption": "false",
                    "licensedContent": false,
                    "regionRestriction": {
                     "blocked": [
                      "GB",
                      "GA",
                      "ZW",
                      "GG",
                      "GF",
                      "GE",
                      "GD",
                      "GI",
                      "GH",
                      "GN",
                      "GM",
                      "GL",
                      "GS",
                      "GR",
                      "GQ",
                      "GP",
                      "GW",
                      "ZA",
                      "GU",
                      "GT",
                      "ZM",
                      "GY",
                      "JE",
                      "LS",
                      "JM",
                      "JO",
                      "MO",
                      "RS",
                      "RO",
                      "JP",
                      "RE",
                      "TZ",
                      "BL",
                      "BM",
                      "BN",
                      "BO",
                      "BH",
                      "BI",
                      "BJ",
                      "BD",
                      "BE",
                      "BF",
                      "BG",
                      "BA",
                      "BB",
                      "BY",
                      "BZ",
                      "BT",
                      "BV",
                      "BW",
                      "BQ",
                      "BR",
                      "BS",
                      "LV",
                      "US",
                      "IN",
                      "UY",
                      "UZ",
                      "UG",
                      "UA",
                      "UM",
                      "AQ",
                      "AS",
                      "AR",
                      "AU",
                      "AT",
                      "AW",
                      "AX",
                      "AZ",
                      "OM",
                      "AE",
                      "AD",
                      "AG",
                      "AF",
                      "AI",
                      "AM",
                      "AL",
                      "AO",
                      "LT",
                      "LB",
                      "LC",
                      "LA",
                      "MK",
                      "TR",
                      "LK",
                      "LI",
                      "TV",
                      "TW",
                      "TT",
                      "TJ",
                      "TK",
                      "TH",
                      "TN",
                      "TO",
                      "TL",
                      "LU",
                      "TC",
                      "LY",
                      "TF",
                      "TG",
                      "TD",
                      "DJ",
                      "DK",
                      "DO",
                      "DM",
                      "DE",
                      "DZ",
                      "ST",
                      "WS",
                      "ME",
                      "KZ",
                      "TM",
                      "WF",
                      "RU",
                      "CO",
                      "CN",
                      "CM",
                      "RW",
                      "CK",
                      "CI",
                      "CH",
                      "CG",
                      "CF",
                      "CD",
                      "CC",
                      "CA",
                      "CZ",
                      "CY",
                      "CX",
                      "CW",
                      "CV",
                      "CU",
                      "CR",
                      "VU",
                      "MZ",
                      "VA",
                      "VC",
                      "VE",
                      "VG",
                      "VI",
                      "MW",
                      "VN",
                      "QA",
                      "NZ",
                      "MV",
                      "FM",
                      "NP",
                      "FI",
                      "FJ",
                      "FK",
                      "YT",
                      "EH",
                      "NI",
                      "FR",
                      "NL",
                      "MS",
                      "NO",
                      "NA",
                      "NC",
                      "YE",
                      "NE",
                      "NF",
                      "NG",
                      "IM",
                      "IL",
                      "IO",
                      "PW",
                      "IE",
                      "ID",
                      "SV",
                      "IQ",
                      "IS",
                      "IR",
                      "IT",
                      "MH",
                      "PF",
                      "PG",
                      "EG",
                      "PE",
                      "MY",
                      "MX",
                      "EC",
                      "PA",
                      "PN",
                      "MT",
                      "PL",
                      "PM",
                      "MQ",
                      "PK",
                      "PH",
                      "MR",
                      "MM",
                      "ML",
                      "PT",
                      "MN",
                      "PR",
                      "PS",
                      "ES",
                      "ER",
                      "MP",
                      "MD",
                      "MG",
                      "MF",
                      "MA",
                      "MC",
                      "PY",
                      "ET",
                      "KW",
                      "EE",
                      "MU",
                      "HK",
                      "HT",
                      "HU",
                      "HR",
                      "NR",
                      "KR",
                      "HN",
                      "KP",
                      "NU",
                      "SG",
                      "HM",
                      "KY",
                      "FO",
                      "KG",
                      "KE",
                      "SZ",
                      "SY",
                      "SX",
                      "KN",
                      "KM",
                      "LR",
                      "SS",
                      "SR",
                      "KI",
                      "KH",
                      "SO",
                      "SN",
                      "SM",
                      "SL",
                      "SK",
                      "SJ",
                      "SI",
                      "SH",
                      "CL",
                      "SE",
                      "SD",
                      "SC",
                      "SB",
                      "SA"
                     ]
                    }
                   }
                  }
                 ]
                }
```

how can i get "blocked" values?
i try this code

```
$response = file_get_contents($yapi);
$my_array = json_decode($response, true);    
$yiusa = $my_array['items'][2]['regionRestriction'][0]['blocked'];
```

it not work

if i try get "id" it work fine but not work with get blocked values

```
 $yidfound = $my_array['items'][0]['id'];
```

result:mWPdC6QB0v4

how can i get values inside "blocked". i want check its include country value like "us"

Comment: There is no item element with a '2' index, there's only 1, hence why it works when you use '0'.

Comment: ok what code i need use? $yiusa = $my_array['items'][0]['regionRestriction'][0]['blocked']; this one also not work

Comment: $yiusa = $my_array['items'][2]['regionRestriction']['blocked'];  use this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code:

```
$data = json_decode($data , true);
var_dump($data['items'][0]['contentDetails']['regionRestriction']['blocked']);
```

Comment: Thanks u its work  this code $yiusa = $my_array['items'][0]['contentDetails']['regionRestriction']['blocked'][0];

Comment: don't forgot to upvote..